# check and remove the array values in Multi-Dimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I designed the system for booking rooms and store the data by multi-dimensional array form.
Now I would like to code the function about finding the array values which duplicating on the time and date (from, to, date).

The logic is a room can be booked one time or more in one day but it cannot booked by one or more users by the same period. For example, John booked 1300-1500 in 15/08/2014 so that no one can book on this period anymore.

I don't know how to implement the function about removing those values while checking although I can understand the logic.

Here is the array (data):

```
    $recordBooking = array(
            "112"=>array(
                "date"=>array(
                    "24/09/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>3,
                            "username"=>"Amy"
                                ),
                        array(   //duplicate data 
                            "from"=>2,
                            "to"=>5,
                            "username"=>"John"
                                )   
                        ),
                    "27/09/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>3,
                            "username"=>"Chars"
                                )
                        ),
                    "29/09/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>5,
                            "username"=>"Peter"
                                )
                        ),
                    "30/09/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>3,
                            "to"=>6,
                            "username"=>"Amy"
                                )
                        )
                    )
                )
        );
```

I want to set the alert message and remove the values which is duplicate when the function is detected the repeat data. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For array filtering there is an [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) function invented. Let’s assume you are already iterating dates:

```
$booked = []; // holder for already booked
$result = array_filter(
  $recordBooking['112']['date']['24/09/2014'], // array value when iterating dates
  function($rb) use (&$booked) { // will filter this date

    foreach($booked as $b) {
      if(
        ($b['from'] < +$rb['from'] && $b['to'] > +$rb['from']) ||
        ($b['from'] < +$rb['to'] && $b['to'] > +$rb['to'])
      ) { // already booked!!!
        echo "ALERT. Skipped: ${rb['username']}\n";
        return false;
      }
    }
    $booked[] = ['from' => +$rb['from'], 'to' => +$rb['to'] ]; // mark time as booked
    return true;
  }
);

var_dump($result); 

// ⇒
/*
ALERT. Skipped: John
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["from"]=>
    int(1)
    ["to"]=>
    int(3)
    ["username"]=>
    string(3) "Amy"
  }
}
*/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for help......Is it possible of using if clause and For-loop to implement the function checking duplicate data?? I am a PHP beginner so I would like to understand easily and I don't want to just find the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is occasionally not a teach-me-please site. BTW, whether you really want to study PHP, you should try to understand the code provided—that likely gives +100 exp, while coding with for-loops and if-clauses leads to write-only spaghetti code.